# Prometheus: Get total amount of data sent over network by prometheus queries

Tags: performance, monitoring, prometheus

I am trying to estimate how much data is sent over our network due to Prometheus queries. This is partly because we would like to move more of our queries to thanos, which would mean more egress traffic from s3 and subsequently more costs.

Would the `prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_sum` be the proper metric to base this query on? Perhaps something like this?
`sum(increase(prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_sum[30d]))`

Queries will be coming both from the prometheus ui directly as well as from grafana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_sum` should cover all HTTP API traffic.

Keep in mind though that Prometheus reads data off disk, so that metric will not cover data that would need to be be read from S3 with Thanos.